# how to declare an array of user defined type in vb6

Tags: arrays, vba, vb6, user-defined-types

```
Type ABFator
    a As Single
    b As Sinlge
End Type

Dim ABFactorArr(8) As ABFactor
```

'Basically I want to declare an array of eight ABFactors which I can then access

I do this and the complier gives error user defined type not defined

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spelling mistake? Missing c?

- You've defined the type as `ABFator` with no c
- and you've put the array as `ABFactor` with a c

You've also mistyped `Single` in your Type definition

Alternatively perhaps you need to make the Type `Public`, in case you are defining it in one module and using it in another?

(Please copy and paste the code into your questions in future, as you've spelt ABFactor three different ways in your question!)

Comment: sorry guys i think i need some cofee

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the code behind of Form1 at the top of the page:

```
Private Type ABFactor
    a As Single
    b As Single
End Type


Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim ABFactorArr(8) As ABFactor
Dim i As Byte
For i = 0 To UBound(ABFactorArr)
    ABFactorArr(i).a = i
    ABFactorArr(i).b = i + 10
Next i
'quick test
Debug.Print ABFactorArr(6).b

End Sub
```

Comment: Correct. There are 3 things we need to be aware of about Type in VB6. First, We need to put it at top of our code file, at lease before functions and subs. Second, We need to use private or public correctly. When we are in private module, we should only use private. At last, when we assign variable of Type we declared, we are assign by value not pointer(address).