# Declaring a Type with a Loop as a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have been tasked with moving a DLL files that was created years ago to a web environment.

I have the Excel spreadsheet and the DLL file but can't read VBA properly and was wondering if someone could help me translate what the header would for the DLL would be

The part I'm having problem with is this, can someone translate this declaration into C, Javascript, or Python.

```
' Structures & External Function Definitions
Type secInfo
    Coupons(0 To 9) As Double         ' size?
    lastCouponDates(0 To 9) As Double ' last date when it is used
End Type
```

I'm not sure it would be

```
struct secInfo
{
    double Coupons[10];
    double lastCouponDates[10];
};


struct secInfo
    {
    double Coupons0;
    double Coupons1;
    double Coupons2;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Your UDT is declaring two types both as double arrays. I'm not entirely sure why you're doing it this way around. I would have thought you would declare both as doubles (not arrays) and then declare an array with this type. e.g. [Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421981/how-to-declare-an-array-of-user-defined-type-in-vb6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct secInfo
{
    double Coupons[10];
    double lastCouponDates[10];
};
```

Is the correct Answer